# HTML onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
<img id="1" src="imgs/1.jpg" border="0" onmouseover="show(1)" onmouseout="hide()">
```

My JS:

```
function show(id) {
makeLayer('LYR1',600,30,300,360,'red',1,1);
}

function hide() {
kill show;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

What I want to do is: when a user mouse is over that image, it will show a new div layer. When a user mouse is out the image, hide this new layer.

Comment: `kill show`? It's not unix :)

Comment: Better do this with css, see for example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp you can chage background, text colors or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the function `makeLayer` from http://www.javascripter.net/faq/creating.htm, then the first argument to the function is the id of the layer element that it creates.  To get rid of the layer element, you find it using its id and then remove it.

```
function hide() {
    var layer = document.getElementById('LYR1');
    layer.parentNode.removeChild(layer);
}
```

I don't know where you got that `kill` idea from, but it's nowhere near correct.

Comment: Thank you! I dont know where i found..but was somewhere in the internet :P

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does support mouseover and mouseout functions too http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/